# Laravel 4 - Get value from another table's field and join to query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I am having a lot of trouble trying to work this query. I'm fairly new to Laravel 4 so go easy.

What I have is 2 tables. Uploads and Albums. Currently, I am trying to output all albums based on user's ID, and grabbing the latest thumbnail of an upload associated with that album.

This is the code I am using currently:

```
DB::table("albums")
->select("albums.*","uploads.thumbnail")
->join("uploads", "uploads.albumid", "=", "albums.id")
->where("albums.userid", "=", Auth::user()->id)
->orderBy("uploads.id", "ASC")
->get()
```

The output is wrong. What the output shows is pretty much the opposite. It's looping through the uploads, rather than albums and retrieving the first record of the albums table.

```
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [userid] => 1
        [private_code] => PJ3r6Ps3c5rRrceKRLvWmpk4o5GvHKHk7QCUnRkTmlwUnxnjmL9kVaOa1N4Tm124
        [slug] => album-test-1
        [name] => Album test 1
        [description] => Album test 1
        [privacy] => Public
        [created_at] => 
        [updated_at] => 
        [thumbnail] => 6s/zj/4e/6SZj4Ev409fU2b3NYHzgW7O9Jn3MFeDb_thumbnail.jpg
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [userid] => 1
        [private_code] => PJ3r6Ps3c5rRrceKRLvWmpk4o5GvHKHk7QCUnRkTmlwUnxnjmL9kVaOa1N4Tm124
        [slug] => album-test-1
        [name] => Album test 1
        [description] => Album test 1
        [privacy] => Public
        [created_at] => 
        [updated_at] => 
        [thumbnail] => 17/zs/11/17zs11CwBKsPilpeMVjH7A7gTEcRxb4P_thumbnail.jpg
    )
)
```

I want to loop through albums, whilst retrieving that album's recent upload thumbnail to use as the thumbnail for the album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some jobs Eloquent is better for.  Since this one doesn't compare fields between the 2 joined tables, you'll have better performance and an easier time with Eloquent since it uses 2 separate `SELECT` queries.

**Album Model:**

```
public function uploads() { return $this->hasMany('Upload', 'albumId') }
```

**Upload Model:**

```
public function album() { return $this->belongsTo('Album', 'albumId') }
```

**Query:**

```
$albums = Album::with(['uploads' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1);
}])->where('userId', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

**Get the thumbnails in a view with:**

```
@foreach($albums as $album)
    {{ $album->uploads->first()->thumbnail }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you. So, so much. You have saved me a massive headache.